# Searching for container for map service

Tags: arcgis-server, configurable-map-viewer

I am currently editing the Configurable Map Viewer so that it can display my map service from local ArcGIS Server.

I can't find which HTML element is the container for the map service. I can not find `"DIV id = map"`.

Does a map to be displayed always contained in `DIV`, or there is another method to display the map on the page?

Answer (score 1):

In Configurable Map Viewer you add map services to the map by editing the [viewer.js](https://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/configure/viewer/)  config file in \viewer\js\config\viewer.js

Look for the [operationalLayers](https://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/configure/operationalLayers/) section.

```
        operationalLayers: [{
        type: 'feature',
        url: 'http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CW_Facilities/FeatureServer/0',
        title: i18n.viewer.operationalLayers.restaurants,
        options: {
            id: 'Facility Assets',
            opacity: 1.0,
            visible: true,
            outFields: ['*'],
            featureReduction: {
                type: 'cluster',
                clusterRadius: 60
            },
            mode: 1
        },
        editorLayerInfos: {
            disableGeometryUpdate: false
        },
        legendLayerInfos: {
            exclude: false,
            layerInfo: {
                title: i18n.viewer.operationalLayers.restaurants
            }
        }
    }],
```